# apache http 80 .htacess, https 443 .htaccess does not work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When I run api.troop37bsa.org/user, I am able to access the page but when I run https://api.troop37bsa.org/user, I get a 404 error.  When I run api.troop37bsa.org/?url=user or the secure version I get the correct page.

I am using a .htaccess file to rewrite the url so that everything after the subdomain is considered a parameter string.

So my question is two fold.  How can I get https://api.troop37bsa.org/user  to work and also what can I do to reduce the size of my .conf file and reduce or merge my .htaccess file.

I have an Apache Server 2.4.18.
My .conf file is setup as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin kreichner@troop37bsa.org
        ServerName api.troop37bsa.org
        ServerAlias api.troop37bsa.org
        DocumentRoot /var/www/troop37bsa.org/api/public

        <Directory /var/www/troop37bsa.org/api/public>
                DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                # Uncomment this directive is you want to see apache2's
                # default start page (in /apache2-default) when you go to /
                #RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
        </Directory>
        AccessFileName .htaccess

        ErrorLog /var/www/troop37bsa.org/api/public/apache_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =api.troop37bsa.org
#RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerAdmin kreichner@troop37bsa.org
        ServerName api.troop37bsa.org
        ServerAlias api.troop37bsa.org
        DocumentRoot /var/www/troop37bsa.org/api/public

        <Directory /var/www/troop37bsa.org/api/public>
                DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                # Uncomment this directive is you want to see apache2's
                # default start page (in /apache2-default) when you go to /
                #RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
        </Directory>
        AccessFileName .htaccess
        ErrorLog /var/www/troop37bsa.org/api/public/apache_https_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined



</VirtualHost>
```

In my subdomain folder (ie /var/www/troop37bsa.org/api/public) I have an .htaccess file

```
ReWriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ %2index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I am also using a letsencrypt SSL certificate that otherwise seems to be working fine.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried disabling .htaccess altogether with AllowOverride none (since you seem to have access to the virtualhost and not need it anyways) and just add a simple "FallBackResource /index.php" in the VirtualHost config for both virtualhosts? If you insist on using that set of rewrites the last condition avoids any normal uri to end up at index.php as you seem to want, that's why /user will give you a 404 if it does not exist.

Comment: @ezra-s Thank you.  That is what I was going for.  The main difficulty seems to have been a .conf file that I did not see before.  It was apparently generated by letsencrypt.  Anyway it was pointing to /publicl not publc.  I removed the l, and removed the virtual host  *443 and the entire site works as expected.

Comment: glad you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment section, It turns out that there was a conf file generated by letsencrypt, but it was pointing to the wrong directory publicl instead of public.  When I changed the directory name. the .htaccess file did its job.  I also removed the second *.443 virtualHost from my orginal conf to avoid further conflicts.

So others may not fall into the same problem the name of the conf was api.troop37bsa.org-le-ssl.conf.  This set up the look ups from the SSL certificate.

the api.troop37bsa.org-le-ssl.conf code is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerAdmin kreichner@troop37bsa.org
        ServerName api.troop37bsa.org
        ServerAlias api.troop37bsa.org
        DocumentRoot /var/www/troop37bsa.org/api/public

        <Directory /var/www/troop37bsa.org/api/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                # Uncomment this directive is you want to see apache2's
                # default start page (in /apache2-default) when you go to /
                #RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/troop37bsa.org/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/troop37bsa.org/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Thank you everyone for your help.